# AWS Lambda request gzip encoding in Java

Tags: java, aws-lambda, gzip

As I know, the input data size limit for Async AWS Lambda functions is just 256Kb. Unfortunately, I hit that limit. I decided to use `gzip` compression since, according to AWS documentation, it's a supported compression algorithm.

This is my function:

```
public class TestHandler implements RequestHandler<TestPojoRequest, String> {
    public String handleRequest(TestPojoRequest request, Context context) {
        return String.valueOf(request.getPojos().size());
    }
}
```

And this is how I invoke it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TestPojoRequest testPojoRequest = new TestPojoRequest();
        TestPojo testPojo = new TestPojo();
        testPojo.setName("name");
        testPojo.setUrl("url");
        List<TestPojo> testPojoList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            testPojoList.add(testPojo);
        }
        testPojoRequest.setPojos(testPojoList);
        String payload = gson.toJson(testPojoRequest);
        invokeLambdaFunction("TestFunction", payload, "us-west-2", "my access id", "my secret");
    }

    private static void invokeLambdaFunction(String functionName, String payload, String region, String accessKeyId, String secretAccessKey) throws IOException {

        LambdaClient client = LambdaClient.builder()
                .region(Region.of(region))
                .credentialsProvider(
                        StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey))
                )
                .build();

        InvokeRequest.Builder builder = InvokeRequest.builder()
                .functionName(functionName)
                .invocationType(InvocationType.REQUEST_RESPONSE)
                .overrideConfiguration(it -> it.putHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip"))
                .payload(SdkBytes.fromByteArray(compress(payload)));
        System.out.println(builder.overrideConfiguration().headers());
        InvokeRequest request = builder.build();
        System.out.println(request);
        InvokeResponse result = client.invoke(request);
        System.out.println(new String(result.payload().asByteArray()));
    }

    public static byte[] compress(final String str) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream obj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
        gzip.write(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        gzip.flush();
        gzip.close();
        return obj.toByteArray();
    }
```

As you may see I put `Content-Encoding` as a header.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. This is my response:

```
Exception in thread "main" software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.InvalidRequestContentException: Could not parse request body into json: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
 at [Source: (byte[])"�V*���/V���V�K�MU��P:J�E9@����%��'"; line: 1, column: 2] (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: cf21cb46-fb1c-4472-a20a-5d35010d5aff)
```

Looks like there was no decompression on the AWS side. What is wrong? I have no idea. I tried to send the payload as a plain text and it worked, so I conclude that either AWS ignores my header or the library that I use doesn't send the header.

Comment: Hi Tony, why don't you just save the input to S3, and the param will contain the path of S3. Just asking to see if you have any constraints for it. I will take a look on the issue you are facing too.

Comment: Hi Tony, I have not found any documentation regarding Compression with Lambda, please share it if you have an url

Comment: why not decompress it yourself in the function Handler

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda doesn't natively accept compressed payload so your code might not work.

Currently I only know "compressed request" can be sent to AWS Lambda using API Gateway.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-gzip-compression-decompression.html

Thanks,